# Vue get dataset type object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to get dataset from refs?
it's working as expected if it's only string or number.

example:

```
template:
  <div ref="data" :data-val="{foo:'bar'}"></div>

inside vue:
  var data = this.$refs.dataset.val
  console.log(data)
```

console.log printed [Object Object] which is just a string instead of actuall object

Comment: JSON.parse(data)

Comment: that is not a string or json data. it's just javascript object. but thanks,. you give me idea to just use string

Comment: You cannot store an object in a dataset value. Dataset values are *always* strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @Bert but it's use v-bind( it's shorthand to ':' ) so it's should can use any javascript valid expression. did u ever using Vue?

Comment: It doesn't matter. `dataset` is a **DOMStringMap**. The value of any of it's properties *is a string*. Yes, I've used Vue extensively :)

Comment: @Bert then, can u give me solution how to get data from server without ajax or parsing it via json. for example i'd want to be able to get data from server in laravel blade template {{ json_encode($serverdata) }}.

Comment: Render it in your javascript. `new Vue({data: {serverData: {{ json_encode($serverdata) }}}})`

Comment: sorry... but how if i running vue on webpack @Bert

Answer (score 0):

[Step 1]
you can store your dataset as json string like below

```
:data-address="JSON.stringify(adr)"
```

[Step 2]
then on read you can convert this to json object like below

```
var selectedItem = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.address);
```